# Click Events / Listeners in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, click

Hey There: I'm having difficulty handling click events with EXTJS.

I define a new widget in the widget View definition, but for whatever reason the following code isn't being called on Click. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Ext.define('MemOS.view.Shortcut', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    alias: 'widget.shortcut',

    name: 'shortcut',
    singleSelect: true,
    store: 'Apps',
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div id="iconGroup" class="icon-wrap">',
                '<div id="icon" class="icon">',
                    '<img src="/images/icons/" />',
                '</div>',
                '<span> {appName} </span>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],  
    itemSelector: 'div.icon',
    listeners: {
        click: function(d, i, n, e){
            alert('foo');
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just make up event names, the list of available ones are here at the bottom: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View